# How to update device twin from device with Azure Python device SDK?

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-sdk-python

I am working with Azure device SDK for Python.

I like to trigger an update of the device twin from the device with the Azure device Python SDK. 
Unfortunately I can not find any samples or even an API documentation which explains how to use it.

Does anyone have an idea how to update device twin in Azure IoT Hub from device with Python SDK?

Regards, Roland

Answer (score 0):

This sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/device/samples/iothub_client_sample_class.py) shows how to update a reported property from the device and receive notification for desired property update.
It also shows how to receive a Methods invocation.
We have more complete documentation for Python coming soon [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-how-to).